# incorrect syntax near System.Data.DataRowViev

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have DatagridView that is connected with combobox control. combobox is used to filter data from a table. combobox and data in  Datagridview are from the same table. i look out for error but a couldn't find. it says:
incorrect syntax near System.Data.DataRowViev

and I click on the ok button and  then other error:
the connection wasn't closed. the connection's current state is open.
please help

```
        private void VraboteniPoOpstini_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                ad = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_PersonalniPodatoci ", con);
                ds = new DataSet();


                ad.Fill(ds, "tbl_PersonalniPodatoci");
                dt = ds.Tables["tbl_PersonalniPodatoci"];
                con.Close();

                //fill combobox
                cbOpstini.DataSource = dt;
                cbOpstini.DisplayMember = "Opstina";
                cbOpstini.ValueMember = "Sifra";

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ГРЕШКА", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }   

        }


        private void cbOpstini_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string izberiOpstina = cbOpstini.SelectedValue.ToString();
            string sSql;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                //datagridview
                sSql = "Select  Sifra, Prezime, Ime, Opstina From tbl_PersonalniPodatoci Where Opstina'" + izberiOpstina + "' Order by Sifra";
                ad = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sSql, con);
                SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(ad);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                ad.Fill(dt);

                con.Close();

                // fill datagridview
                grdOpstini.DataSource= dt;


            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ГРЕШКА", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }


        }
```

Comment: "Incorrect syntax" Yeah, where's your code?

Comment: please post only the relevant code!

Answer (score 0):

As Henk already said - you need to take more care for your connections, how you open and close them. Also: if you use the `SqlDataAdapter`, there's really no need for you to manually open the connection and close it again - the data adapter will do this automatically for you.

And also: in the first example, you only need a single data table, yet you create a data set and then extract the table from it - that's totally unnecessary overhead.

Try something like this:

```
private void VraboteniPoOpstini_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
       // add a "using System.Data.SqlClient" to your file, to make this simpler
       ad = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_PersonalniPodatoci ", con);

       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       ad.Fill(dt);

       //fill combobox
       cbOpstini.DataSource = dt;
       cbOpstini.DisplayMember = "Opstina";
       cbOpstini.ValueMember = "Sifra";
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ГРЕШКА", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
   }   
}
```

You can do a similar approach (use `DataTable` right away, no need to open and close SqlConnection when using SqlDataAdapter etc.) for your second query.

Comment: I try to find error, add like in sql query, and now there isn't any error. but still doesn't work. I couldn't connect my combobox control with DatagridView.